# How to return an 'onclick' Attribute?

Tags: javascript

If I remove an `onclick` attribute, how can I set it back on the same element with the first function that was applied on the `onclick` event.

For example `function show(clicked_id)` // gets the user id by clicking.

I dont want the user to click twice on the same id so I use a `remove` attribute.
Then I want to change it back the way it was.

```
function getthepic(m) {
    GetPic.setAttribute("src", randomImages[m]);
    x.appendChild(GetPic);
    StorePics[i] = randomImages[m];
    StoreIds[i] = x;
    counter++;
    i++;
    CheckValve = false;

    StoreIds[0].removeAttribute("onclick");
}

setTimeout(function() {
    if (counter == 2) {
        StoreIds[0].innerHTML = "";
        StoreIds[1].innerHTML = "";
        var getCard = document.createElement('img');
        getCard.setAttribute("src", 'images/blank.png');
        StoreIds[0].appendChild(getCard);
        var getCard2 = document.createElement('img');
        getCard2.setAttribute("src", 'images/blank.png');
        StoreIds[1].appendChild(getCard2);
        counter = 0;
        i = 0;
        StorePics[0] = "";
        StorePics[1] = "";
        StoreIds[0] = "";
        StoreIds[1] = "";
        StorePics.pop();
        StoreIds.pop();
        StorePics[0].setAttribute('onclick', show(clicked_id);
    }
  
    CheckValve = true;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: attributes need to be a ***string*** - so, make it a string

Comment: `StorePics[0].setAttribute('onclick', show(clicked_id);` is a syntax error, you also need to pass a function, not a function call: `StorePics[0].setAttribute('onclick', () => show(clicked_id));`

Comment: Also set a flag instead of adding removing

Comment: @ChrisG , it doesnt work the way you suggested..

Comment: @mplungjan how can i do the flag suggestion i dont know what it means

Comment: im gettin an error of : 
JavaScript.js:112 Uncaught TypeError: StorePics[0].setAttribute is not a function
    at JavaScript.js:112

Comment: @avihu24 Perhaps use [the code from your deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68206776/295783) as a [mcve]:

Comment: You already have the flag: CheckValve = false/true

Comment: i dont know how to use a flag for the onclick attrbuite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234409/discussion-between-avihu24-and-mplungjan).